# Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, request, scrapy

I have coded a simple spider to retrieve information of quotes:

```
import scrapy

class GoodReadsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    #identity
    name = 'goodreads'

    #requests
    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1",
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback= self.parse)

    #response
    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.selector.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
            yield {
                'text': quote.xpath(".//blockquote[@class='quoteBody']/text()[1]").extract_first(),
                'author': quote.xpath(".//span[@class='quoteAuthor']/text()").extract_first(),
                'tag': quote.xpath(".//div[@class='quoteTags']/a/text()").extract(),
            }
```

When I run it I get however the following error:

```
Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because your URL is a [*tuple*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), due to the trailing comma in its definition. The actual message should tell you this - what you've posted is the line that raised that error, not the resulting message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `start_requests` for `url` you have comma in the end of line, so it thinks that `url` is a tuple.

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = "https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1",  # <- remove comma here
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback= self.parse)
```

Comment: Thank you! What an easy mistake :D